# The laravel controller don't receive the data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

My problem is that,when I send all the information by JS, it is fine but my controller doesn't receive data.
I need send all the information inside the form and an object array.
I am using Laravel and Ajax /Jquery.

**JS / Jquery /Ajax code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#BtnRegistrar').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize(); 
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {data:dataString, list:cursos}, //Here load the form data and my array of objects
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Done');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Laravel.blade.php**

```
           <form method="post" action="/coordinacionCarrera/agregarNombramiento" id="formulario">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="docente">Escoja el docente.</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                                <i class="fas fa-id-card"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select required class="form-select" name="usuario" id="usuario">
                                <option selected>Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach ($usuario as $user)
                                <option value={{$user->id}}>{{$user->persona->Cedula}} | {{$user->persona->Nombre}} {{$user->persona->PrimerApellido}} {{$user->persona->SegundoApellido}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="Desde">Desde.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Desde" id="vigencia" value="{{old('Desde')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="Hasta">Hasta.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Hasta" id="vigencia2" value="{{old('Hasta')}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mtop16">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="Categoria">Categoría.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select disabled class="form-select" name="categoria" id="categoria">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CategoriaActual" id="CategoriaActual" value="0">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="correo">Correo.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select disabled class="form-select" name="correo" id="correo">
                                <input type="hidden" name="CorreoActual" id="CorreoActual" value="0">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="Telefono">Teléfono.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select disabled class="form-select" name="telefono" id="telefono">
                                <input type="hidden" name="TelefonoActual" id="TelefonoActual" value="0">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mtop16">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="Curso">Escoja el curso.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select required class="form-select" name="curso" id="curso">
                                <option selected value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach ($curso as $cursos)
                                <option value={{$cursos->IDCurso}}>{{$cursos->Codigo}} | {{$cursos->Nombre}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="Tipo">I/C.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select required class="form-select" name="Tipo" id="Tipo">
                                <option selected value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach (obtenerTipoDeCurso() as $Tipo=>$id)
                                <option value="{{$id}}">{{$Tipo}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <label for="Tutoria">Tutoría.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input class="ms-3 mt-3" name="Tutoria" id="Tutoria" type="checkbox" value="0">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="CargaAcademica">Carga Académica.</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                            </span>
                            <select required class="form-select" name="CargaAcademica" id="CargaAcademica">
                                <option selected value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                @foreach (ObtenerCargaAcademica() as $CargaAcademica=>$id)
                                <option value="{{$id}}">{{$CargaAcademica}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 mtop16">
                        <a onclick='AgregarCursoDocente()' class="btn btn-plus">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus-square fs-2"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mtop16" id="CursoDocente">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="mtop16 btn btn-success" id="BtnRegistrar">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Controller function**

```
public function postAñadirNombramiento(Request $request)
    {
        return $request; //Here im trying to capture the data
    }
```

**Console browser when i press submit button**
[image]

Someone knows why am I not receiving anything? Or there is any other method by which I can send the form inputs and an array of objects created in Javascript?

Comment: How do you know you're not receiving anything? All you're doing in your controller is returning your request back to the ajax, and in your ajax, you're just writing "Done". Have you checked the Network tab to see what's being returned? Have you tried to do anything else with the request in your controller function?

Comment: Because i can see the data on the controller with return or dd(), and if i try to redirect to another site or similar (without use the request) no works, for example that when i press submit the controller redirect me at another site but no work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here

```
 success: function(data) {
                console.log('Done');
            }
```

the request is successfully reaching your controller you are just logging "done" every time
replace it with

```
 success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
```

Comment: Now i understand a little bit more of JQuery (I send the information without recharge the website), now i'm getting the data on the controller and i can manipulate (CRUD) with this information. Thank you!